# Unable to retain the form filter value after successfully searching the Users based on User Groups in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am able to search the security user groups successfully. But while pressing the search button, the search value is getting vanished with the search results. I want the search value to be retained in the search field until I manually remove it or refresh the page.

I am overriding the django admin Groups model and this is the field that I am trying to search from the UserListView.

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    groups              = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_group', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
class UsersListView(AdminRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = "users"
    template_name = "list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.model.objects.all().select_related("groups")
        request_post = self.request.POST
        if request_post:
            if request_post.get('groups'):
                queryset = queryset.filter(groups_id=request_post.get('groups'))
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UsersListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["groups_list"] = User.objects.all()
        return context
```

Templates:
This is how I am searching the groups field in template.

HTML Code:

```html
              <div class="filter_col col-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Group</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="id_groups" name="groups">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">--Select an User Group--</option>
                    {% for group in groups_list %}
                    <option value="{{group.groups.id}}" {%ifequal group.groups.id request.POST.group.groups|add:"0"%} selected {%endifequal%}>{{ group.groups.name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Can someone please help, when I select the security group option (Admin, Staff, etc) in the search filter and press the search button. The search is successful with all the users with that particular security group is filtered. But, I am losing the search value in the filter. I would like to retain it. Please help me to understand what am I missing here.